# What is a good solution for patching a tear in a canvas rag top?

Tags: repair

I have a tear about 3-4 inches long on my canvas rag top. The cost of a new one is 700 bucks and I rather not pay that if I can get away with a patch for now. Any suggestions?

Comment: Probably highly depends on the location of the tear. I imagine it should be easier to fix if it's in the middle of the roof than if it's on the seam or around the window. A photo will increase the chance of a good answer.